# Warning C6387 when using SetIcon

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, statusbar, code-analysis

Code:

```
m_hStatusBarZoomFactorIcon =
        CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::HICONFromCBitmap(
m_mapMenuBitmap[MAKEWPARAM(MenuNavigation::View, SubMenuPos::Zoom)]);
    VERIFY(m_hStatusBarZoomFactorIcon);
    m_StatusBar.GetStatusBarCtrl().SetIcon(
        to_underlying(StatusBarPane::ProgressOrZoomFactor), m_hStatusBarZoomFactorIcon);
```

The variables are `HICON` and `CStatusBar` respectively. Why am I getting this warning?

> Warning   [C6387](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6387?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C6387)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-160)  `m_hStatusBarZoomFactorIcon` could be `0`:  this does not adhere to the specification for the function `CStatusBarCtrl::SetIcon`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add code to check that `m_hStatusBarZoomFactorIcon` is valid (i.e. *not* null) before calling the `SetIcon()` function with that as a parameter:

```cpp
m_hStatusBarZoomFactorIcon =
    CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::HICONFromCBitmap(
        m_mapMenuBitmap[MAKEWPARAM(MenuNavigation::View, SubMenuPos::Zoom)]);
//  VERIFY(m_hStatusBarZoomFactorIcon); // vide infra
    if (m_hStatusBarZoomFactorIcon) { // Only use it if it's valid ...
        m_StatusBar.GetStatusBarCtrl().SetIcon(
            to_underlying(StatusBarPane::ProgressOrZoomFactor), 
            m_hStatusBarZoomFactorIcon);
    }
    else {
        // Error handling code
    }
```

Note: If you were relying on the `VERIFY(m_hStatusBarZoomFactorIcon);` statement to take care of that check then note that that expands to *effectively* nothing unless the `_DEBUG` macro is also defined (i.e. in debug builds). From afx.h:

```cpp
//...
#else   // _DEBUG

#define VERIFY(f)          ((void)(f))
///
```

Comment: Thanks. I have wrapped it in a `if` test. But concerning `VERIFY` the official dicumentation states: * The `VERIFY` macro evaluates its own arguments in both debug and release builds of the application.*.

Comment: Well, technically, yeah - its argument ***is*** being evaluated; but nothing is being done with the result of that evaluation. With `_DEBUG` defined, it becomes: `#define VERIFY(f) ASSERT(f)`.

Comment: Kinda pointless then isn't it! Just as well use `ASSERT` ...

Comment: Far be it from me to accuse anything that Microsoft does as being *pointless*. :)

Comment: Alternatively, make `HICONFromCBitmap` always return a non-`NULL` value on success (and report errors through C++ exceptions).

Comment: Why not `ENSURE`?